# Getting unexpected output for string array

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, printf, c-strings

```
a = 1;
b = 9;
char s[9][5]={"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
{
  if(i<10)
     printf("%s\n",s[i-1]);
  else
    {
      if(i%2==1)
         printf("odd\n");
      else
         printf("even\n");
    }  
}
```

expected:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
```

got:

```
one
two
threefour
four
five
six
seveneightnine
eightnine
nine
```

Comment: Count the number of bytes your strings need again.

Comment: A string is by definition a sequence of non-zero `char`s, terminated by a `char` with value zero. For an array to hold such a sequence, it needs space for the terminating zero. If there is no zero, it is not a string, and treating it like a string makes no sense.

Comment: Unless you intend to modify those strings, the safest way to declare the array is `char *s[] = { "one", "two", "etc..." };` That way you don't need to think about how long the strings are, or even how many are in the array. If you need to know the number of strings in the array, use `size_t count = sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all elements of this array

```
char s[9][5]={"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
```

contain a string. The type of elements is `char[5]`. So for example the string literal `"three"` is not completely contained in the third element of the array because there is no space to store the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal and the conversion specifier `%s` is designed to output characters until the terminating zero character `'\0'` is encountered. This is the reason of the appearance of such an output like

```
threefour
seveneightnine
eightnine
```

So either you need to increase the size of elements of the array like

```
char s[9][6]= { /*...*/ };
```

or to use the following format string in the call of `printf`

```
printf("%.*s\n", 5, s[i-1]);
```

Pay attention to that this if statement

```
  if(i<10)
```

does not make a great sense because i is always less than 10.